# JSON file is being cleared if I refresh the page continuous

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I use `fs` module to read/write my JSON files. But if I restart the page fast, my JSON file is being cleared.

I read the JSON data at begining of the page.

```
let preferencesJSON;
try {
    preferencesJSON = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/../preferences.json", {encoding:'utf-8', flag:'r'})
} catch(e) {
    throw e;
}
const preferencesObj = JSON.parse(preferencesJSON);
```

In a different script, I use `fs` for write to a JSON file.

```
preferencesWelcomeJSON = preferencesObj;
preferencesWelcomeJSON.welcome = false;
fs.writeFile(__dirname+"/../preferences.json", JSON.stringify(preferencesObj), function(err, data){});
```

Comment: It appears possible that you're writing the file to a different location than the one you're reading upon startup because of different values for `__dirname`.  Check the time stamp on the one you're reading at startup and see if it's really getting updated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of multiprocess file access.

You need to lock the file while you are writing to it so nothing else is reading from it at the same time.

Typically this is done by:

1. Creating another file (e.g. yourfile.pid) containing the process id of the program doing the write just before you write to it
2. Doing the file write
3. Deleting the pid file

while at the same time the read process:

1. Checks to see if a pid file exists
2. If it does, wait and then check again (in a loop)
3. Read the file only while no pid file exists

Then you have to deal with the possibility of scripts crashing and leaving stale lock files behind.

There are modules like [proper-lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proper-lockfile) that can help with this.

---

A better solution is to **not use JSON for storing data that changes**.

Use a real database instead. That will solve your file locking problems automatically.

Generate the JSON from the database on demand (instead of reading it from a static file).

Comment: WHAAAT!!! OMG, I didn't know so much is needed. My answer was totally waste!